# How to avoid the user from repeating to fill in the form if there is an error?

Tags: javascript, html

Problem: I'm doing a form to be filled by the user. Once the user clicks submit, if there is an error in the form, it will show an alert. However, when the user clicks "ok" the form will reset all the fields that have been filled so the user needs to repeat in fill in the form all over again.

Question: How to fix this so that when the user clicks "ok" the data is still there?

Answer (score 1):

To stop the page from re-loading add `return false;` after alert statement, it stops the default action from taking place from the form submit.

```
alert("Please fill in all mandatory fields");
return false;
```

Comment: hey, thanks but I already did this and I think return false is not what made the form not to reset.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset form:

```
document.getElementById("formId").reset();
```

Comment: form reset does the exact opposite of what the OP is looking for. [check it out](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_reset)

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` element, when placed in a form, will submit the form automatically unless otherwise specified. You can use the following 2 strategies:

- Use `<button type="button">` to override default submission behavior.
- Use event.preventDefault() in the onSubmit event to prevent form
  submission.

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
form.addEventListener('onSubmit', handleForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something that does exactly that. It's a complete working code, but I am going to give you the task of figuring out which part does what.

```js
function submitInfo(e){
  var fields = document.getElementsByClassName('input-field').length;
  for(let x = 0; x < fields; x++){
    var value = document.getElementById(x).value;
    if(value == ''){
       e.preventDefault();
     var element = document.getElementById(x);
     element.classList.add('no-value');
     setTimeout(function(){
        element.classList.remove('no-value')
     },3000);
     break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.no-value {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="input-field" id="0"/><br/>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-field" id="1"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitInfo(event)"/>
</form>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That’s great. Don’t forget to accept an answer that helped you so that other people can be helped by it.